# Correct way to use AFHTTPSessionManager as a singleton?

Tags: afnetworking-2

I'm trying to use AFNetworking 2.0 to perform my network requests but I'm running into some odd behavior.  I've subclassed `AFHTTPSessionManager` as [suggested in the documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html) and provided a class method that returns a singleton object that has the base url set as well as sets my auth header.

```
+ (id)sharedInstance {
  static dispatch_once_t once;
  static MyHTTPClient *sharedInstance;

  dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL: NSURLURLWithString:kPlatformAPIBaseURL]];
  });

  //Uncommenting this line makes the error go away
  //sharedInstance.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

  //get latest session id everytime someone gets an instance of the client
  sharedInstance.sessionId = [MySessionManager getSessionId];

  return sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
  self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];

  if(self) {
    self.sessionId = [FSSessionManager getSessionId];

    self.serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    [_serializer setValue:_sessionId forHTTPHeaderField:kAuthorizationHeader];
    [_serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:kAcceptHeader];

    self.requestSerializer = _serializer;
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)setSessionId:(NSString *)sessionId {
  _sessionId = sessionId;
  [self.serializer setValue:_sessionId forHTTPHeaderField:kAuthorizationHeader];
}
```

My app uses this to make a POST request to authenticate my user.  That works great.  I then make a GET request to retrieve a list of objects.  Also works great.  I then make the same GET request and I get back a network error `Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/json"`  It's the exact same GET request but it fails on the second call.  When I uncomment the `sharedInstance.responseSerializer` line so I create a new instance of the response serializer each time I get a reference to my shared instance then I don't get this error anymore.

Can a responseSerializer not be used multiple times safely? It feels like some sort of state is hanging around across requests.  What's the correct way to set this up?

Comment: A `responseSerializer` can be used multiple times safely.  Are you changing `responseSerializer` anywhere in your POST (authentication) code?

Comment: What is `self.serializer`?  I don't see that in the AFHTTPSessionManager or AFURLSessionManager interfaces.

Comment: Originally, I didn't even set a responseSerializer.  I tried setting it once in the initWithBaseUrl method but had the same problem.  Only if I'm setting it every time I request the shared instance does the error go away.

Comment: self.serializer is a property I added to my subclass that holds a reference to the `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` instance I make in the initWithBaseUrl method.  I hold a reference so I can change my session id when it changes.

Comment: @AaronBrager your original comment was right on...we went back through all of our response handlers and we were setting our responseSerializer in once case to handle image downloads and never setting it back.  I'd be happy to mark your comment as the answer if you want to add it as an answer.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A response serializer can be used multiple times safely. Based on the error message you posted, "unacceptable content-type: application/json ", it appears you're setting `responseSerializer` to something else elsewhere in your code.  JSON will serialize properly as long as it's set to `[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]`.

Comment: This answer saved me so much time! Thanks @Aaron! In my case, I was setting the `responseSerializer` to `AFJSONResonseSerializer` while downloading a list of photo messages and then when downloading each photo, `responseSerializer` was being set to `AFImageResponseSerializer`. Reusing the shared client didn't quite for the reason explained in the answer.

Comment: @indyfromoz You may want to consider making a compound serializer, which parses JSON if it's JSON, or an image if it's an image.